# Extending functional inequality from rectangles to parallelograms

Tags: inequalities, plane-geometry, l-functions

Let $f$ be a function defined on the unit square $R = [0,1]^2 \subseteq \mathbf{R}^2$ satisfying

- $f \geq 0$, $f(0,0) = 0$,
- $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} \geq 0$, $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} \leq 0$,
- $\frac{\partial^2{f} }{\partial{x}\partial{y}} \leq 0$.

The last condition is equivalent to the inequality $f(x_1,y_1) + f(x_2,y_2) \geq f(\min\left(x_1,x_2\right), \min\left(y_1,y_2\right)) + f(\max\left(x_1,x_2\right), \max\left(y_1,y_2\right))$ on any rectangle, which can be obtained by integrating $\frac{\partial^2{f} }{\partial{x}\partial{y}}$ over the rectangle.

If we label the vertices of the rectangle counterclockwise $v_1, \dots, v_4$, starting at the upper right, this is saying that $f(v_2) + f(v_4) \geq f(v_1) + f(v_3)$.

Does this property also hold for parallelograms inscribed in $R$ with wlog $v_1 = (1,1), v_3 = (0,0)$?

For $v_2 = (x_2,y_2)$, $v_4 = (x_1,y_1)$, the linear function mapping $R$ to the parallelogram $P$ is

\begin{pmatrix}
&x_1 & x_2 \\
&y_1 & y_2
\end{pmatrix}

After change of variables the differential condition on $P$ can then be written

$(x_1y_2 + y_1x_2)f_{xy} + x_1x_2f_{xx} + y_1y_2f_{yy}$, I don't know that that is necessarily nonpositive.

Note that without the first bullet condition, the answer is no [Planar function inequality on parallelograms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381405/planar-function-inequality-on-parallelograms).

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes with the additional condition - proof?

Comment: I think "inscribed into $D$" usually means "contained in $D$, with all vertices on the boundary of $D$". Is this what you mean by "inscribed" here?

Comment: Note that the first bullet condition is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for instance $f(x,y)=x^2$, that satisfies the assumptions.  Since one has $f(x,y)+f(1-x,1-y)= 1-2x+2x^2 < 1=f(0,0)+f(1,1)$ for all $0<x<1$, it verifies the stated inequality for no parallelogram (inscribed in $R$, with vertices in $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$) with non-vertical edges.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this does it. I haven't looked at counterexamples enough apparently. The property follows trivially if I also assume subadditivity of $f$ (or 2-subhomogeneity, since $f$ is convex), but then that and the first bullet are sufficient, no partial deriv constraints needed. I was looking to avoid a subadditivity assumption...